# How to fetch feeds from LinkedIn Profile by using Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to fetch feeds from LinkedIn profile (it can be profile / a company page). i created LinkedIn developer app. I have permissions for

openid
profile
r_organization_social
rw_organization_admin
w_member_social
w_organization_social
r_basicprofile
r_organization_admin
email
r_1st_connections_size

But too, I couldn't able to find the proper output.

I tried the ugcposts,
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn:li:person:me)

but I got,
`{ "serviceErrorCode": 100, "message": "Field Value validation failed in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/authors]", "status": 403 }`

I also tried with v2/share, whatever i try, output is the same.

Please If anyone can help me regarding this?